# Custom controller to call one specific record from a custom object

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller

I created a custom object named '**Live_Chat_Switch__c**' with one custom field '**Enable_chat__c**' (boolean) and I would like to call that field of a specific record on a VF page.

To do so, I created a custom controller :

```
global class Chat_switch 
{
    public Live_Chat_Switch__c liveChatSwitch; 


    public Live_Chat_Switch__c getLive_Chat_Switch() 
    {
         return 
            [
                SELECT Enable_chat__c 
                FROM Live_Chat_Switch__c 
                WHERE Id = 'a4hg0000000EfUj'
            ];
    }

}
```

And this is the code on my VF page :

```
<apex:Page controller="Chat_Switch">

    <apex:outputField value="{!liveChatSwitch.Enable_chat__c}"/>
```

But I can't build it and it says 'Unknown property 'Chat_switch.liveChatSwitch'...
Any idea ?

Comment: You should never hard-code an `Id` into your `Apex` code. This is a big anti-pattern that you should avoid **at all costs**.

Comment: Any reason you did not place this data into a Custom Settings record? That seems like a much better fit for this type of application control.

Comment: @MarkPond Agreed. Specifically it seems like this should be a `Hierarchy Custom Setting`.

Comment: You are completely right, I did it now. Thank you very much for your advice, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `getter`/`setter`:

```
public Live_Chat_Switch__c liveChatSwitch { get; private set; }
```

As your original controller is written, `liveChatSwitch` is not a [property](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm).

Also note that if you renamed your method from `getLive_Chat_Switch` to `getLiveChatSwitch`, that would define the `getter` you need for `liveChatSwitch` to become a `property`. However, defining the getter as you have it is suboptimal as it runs a query; you should cache the results to avoid running it every time the `getter` is called.